# Deserializing Many Json Objects into List - C#

Tags: c#, json, list, deserialization

So I've been looking all over the web, read countless threads and have yet to find an answer to this little problem I have.

So I have this large json file I need to deserialize into a list of objects.

The purpose is so that a user can search an item name from the list, which will then use that item's id # to search another portion of the api that simply returns info on that one single item. 
I have the other portion all figured out and working, but this part I can't seem to get right.

Here is an example of the json:

```
{"2": {"name": "Cannonball", "buy_average": 173, "sell_average": 174, "overall_average": 174, "id": 2, "members": true, "sp": 5}, "6": {"name": "Cannon base", "buy_average": 173398, "sell_average": 177731, "overall_average": 186396, "id": 6, "members": true, "sp": 187500}, "12289": {"name": "Mithril platelegs (t)", "buy_average": 2473, "sell_average": 2473, "overall_average": 0, "id": 12289, "members": false, "sp": 2600}, "8": {"name": "Cannon stand", "buy_average": 184003, "sell_average": 184471, "overall_average": 185564, "id": 8, "members": true, "sp": 187500}, "10": {"name": "Cannon barrels", "buy_average": 183594, "sell_average": 185125, "overall_average": 188186, "id": 10, "members": true, "sp": 187500}, "12": {"name": "Cannon furnace", "buy_average": 175920, "sell_average": 178136, "overall_average": 187000, "id": 12, "members": true, "sp": 187500}, "4099": {"name": "Mystic hat (dark)", "buy_average": 11350, "sell_average": 11754, "overall_average": 11956, "id": 4099, "members": true, "sp": 15000}, "28": {"name": "Insect repellent", "buy_average": 450, "sell_average": 707, "overall_average": 750, "id": 28, "members": true, "sp": 3}, "30": {"name": "Bucket of wax", "buy_average": 0, "sell_average": 350, "overall_average": 350, "id": 30, "members": true, "sp": 6}, "4101": {"name": "Mystic robe top (dark)", "buy_average": 71235, "sell_average": 71800, "overall_average": 73595, "id": 4101, "members": true, "sp": 120000}, "36": {"name": "Candle", "buy_average": 173, "sell_average": 215, "overall_average": 217, "id": 36, "members": true, "sp": 3}, "39": {"name": "Bronze arrowtips", "buy_average": 7, "sell_average": 9, "overall_average": 10, "id": 39, "members": true, "sp": 1}, "40": {"name": "Iron arrowtips", "buy_average": 4, "sell_average": 4, "overall_average": 5, "id": 40, "members": true, "sp": 2}, "41": {"name": "Steel arrowtips", "buy_average": 25, "sell_average": 27, "overall_average": 30, "id": 41, "members": true, "sp": 6}.......
```

For the full file : https://rsbuddy.com/exchange/summary.json

Now my class looks like this:

```
    public class ItemSummary
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public int buy_average { get; set; }

    public int sell_average { get; set; }

    public int overall_average { get; set; }

    public int id { get; set; }

    public bool members { get; set; }

    public int sp { get; set; }


}
```

My code for deserializing:

```
     public string getitemsummaryraw()
    {
        apisource = "https://rsbuddy.com/exchange/summary.json";

        try
        {
            webreq = WebRequest.Create(apisource);
            webres = webreq.GetResponse();
            webstream = webres.GetResponseStream();

            using (sr = new StreamReader(webstream))
            {
                jsonstring = sr.ReadToEnd();
                return jsonstring;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return null;
        }
    }


public List<ItemSummary> getitemsummary()
    {

        string rawjson = getitemsummaryraw();

        if (rawjson != null)
        {
            var itemlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<ItemSummary>>>(rawjson);
            var items = itemlist.SelectMany(entry => entry.Value);
            return items.ToList<ItemSummary>();


        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[OSRS_Item_Logger.ItemSummary]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
```

Any help?
I've been struggling with this and really could use some help here.

My apologies, it was 4 am when I wrote this. Also this is not homework at all. This is something I'm working on in my own time.
I added the rest of the code for the json deserialization.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. At the moment we have a class with multiple members, a large chunk of JSON, and an incomplete piece of code doing the deserialization. (I'd also strongly advise you to start following .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: I think you should deserialize to `Dictionary<string, ItemSummary>`

Comment: You are trying to deserialize a JSON object to a list, which won't work. You need to either have a JSON array in the text file or serialize to a single, non-collection object

Comment: SO isn't a homework writing service.

Comment: Not homework, I updated the post with the rest of the code, and sorry for the mistake as it was around 4 am when I posted this and I was nodding off. Anyway, so I should just edit the json to be an array? That seems like that may be my easiest alternative at this point.

Comment: The suggestion by @mshsayem is correct.

Comment: Thanks the feedback. I'm attempting using an alternative api to make this process easier and require a less complex c# object to deserialize. I posted a thread about it, but perhaps I should have just edited this thread? Not sure, sorry. I'm knew to posting on these forums. Been a browser for a long time but never truly posted until this.